C# VSTO outlook creating meeting without invation
I am developing an addin for outlook. Is there any way to create a meeting without sending an invitation via outlook to all meeting participants?

Sidenote. Be aware that the new outlook won't support VSTO anymore. If that will be a new Addin reconsidering your decision to use VSTO. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/one-outlook

You can create an appointment/meeting in an Outlook folder using MAPIFolder.Items.Add / AppointmentItem.Save.
